# Drupal: module for handling public and private files storage

Tags: drupal, drupal-modules

I need to create a web system for handling public file downloads and to create protected directories for single users. Users can see the content of the public folder and can read/write in their directory without, obviously, seeing the content of other users directories. I would like to use Drupal but I have not found a module that permits a similar thing.
Can anyone suggest me links to useful modules?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It sounds like the [User Files module](http://drupal.org/project/user_files) does what you're looking for.